# Select all XML elements whose name starts with a certain string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I have two elements, `item` and `date`:

- `item` has_many dates
- `date` belongs_to item

I have a file with XML tree like this:

```
<content>
  <item_1>
    <title>
    <description>
    <date_1>
      <date></date>
      <count></count>
    </date_1>
    <date_2>
      <date></date>
      <count></count>
    </date_2>
  </item_1>
  <item_2>
    <title>
    <description>
    <date_1>
      <date></date>
      <count></count>
    </date_1>
    <date_2>
      <date></date>
      <count></count>
    </date_2>
  </item_2>
</content>
```

I use Nokogiri for parsing data from `item` and `date`.
I wrote a half of the script, which creates elements:

```
doc.xpath("//content/*").each do |item|
  Item.create!(
              title: item.xpath("title").text,
              description: item.xpath("description").text)
end
```

Now I need find and build all dates of the items (element `date`), but can't understand how to parse tags like `<data_1>`, `<data_2>`, `<data_3>` etc.
What I was trying

```
  tour.xpath("//*/data_*").each do |date|
    puts date
  end
```

or

```
  tour.xpath{ |i| "//*/data_#{i}" }.each do |date|
    puts date
  end
```

but it doesn't work or I get an error.

Comment: "i get error" means? It tells us nothing. Perhaps specifying the exact exception you get would help.

Comment: That means regexp doesn't work inside xpath()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The XPath for selecting all `date` elements in your document, regardless of their heritage, is simply:

```
//date
```

The XPath for selecting all elements whose name starts with "date_" is:

```
//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'date_')]
```

See [`starts-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with) and [`local-name()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-local-name).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
doc.xpath("//content/*").each do |item|
  ...
  item.xpath("./*[starts-with(local-name(), 'date_')]").each do |d|
    ...
  end
end
```

(snipped edited according to @kjhughes suggestion)

Comment: While this should work, it's going to be slower. You're asking Nokogiri to return all nodes inside the `content` node, then have Ruby filter them out. It's always better to let the "engine" do the work, i.e., let libXML or a DBM reduce the "hits" as much as possible for speed, then work with the reduced results.

Comment: Agreed. I will update the snippet according di @kjhughes suggestion.